# how to method calling with single parameters in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, parameter-passing

I have the following button:

```
UIButton *Training=[[UIButton alloc]init];
    Training.frame=CGRectMake(160,139.33, 80, 69.33);
    [Training addTarget:self action:@selector(aTraining:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
[self.view addSubview:Training];
```

When the button is clicked, I need to pass the NString value to the other ViewController. I have tried using:

```
-(void)aTraining:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"aTraining");
    callingString=@"Training";
     [self calling];
}
-(void)calling
{
    show=[[Showdeals alloc]initWithNibName:@"Showdeals" bundle:nil];
    //show.setText=callingString;

    NSLog(@"callingString%@",callingString);
    [self.view addSubview:show.view];
}
```

I tried like this but my String value is not being passed to the controller method. Can someone tell me how to call the method with parameters?

Please help me. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: replace -(void)calling {} with -(void)callingWithParameter:(NSString*)string. and call it.  its really very basic.

Comment: This is basic idea in programming with Objective C, go back and read Apple's documentation https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210

Answer (score 1):

replace `-(void)calling {}` with `-(void)callingWithParameter:(NSString*)string`. and call it. its really very basic.

Answer (score 0):

If you are simply trying to leverage a value across multiple methods, then you could just set a property in the interface section of our VC

```
@interface myVC ()
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *callingString;
@end
```

Then

```
// to set
self.callingString = @"Training";
// to access
NSLog(@"%@", _callingString);
```

If you are trying to set a property in another VC then in your prepareForSegue method:

```
MyOtherViewController *destinationVC = (MyOtherViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
        destinationVC.callingString = _callingString;
```

or you could do as Pawan says and update your method signature

or, you could clarify your question further and we'll give you a few more pointers